# Increment count by 0.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm aware of ActiveRecord's `increment_counter`...but I need to increment something by `0.5` instead of `1`.

Something like: `User.increment_counter(:credits_count, RECORD_ID, 0.5)`

Is there some sort of helper/method for easily incrementing by `0.5`? Or do I have to pull the record, get the current count and then add `0.5` to that count and save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.increment`

So basically would be `User.find(RECORD_ID).increment(:credits_count, 0.5)`

[Api Doc Increment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want all the loading of the object to make it faster, use update_all

```
def self.increment_float(user_id,counter,value)
  User.update_all("#{counter} = #{counter} + #{value}",{:id => user_id})
end
```

be carefull since update_all updates EVERYTHING that matches the where condition (in this case id == user_id), maybe you want to do some tests before to be sure